# Detecting duplicate video by analyzing raw compressed data C++

Tags: c++, video, compression, computer-vision

I was just about to write a "quick" program to test a theory of mine and realized how much code it would take to possibly fail, so I thought I'd be lazy and see if anyone else had tried it first.

My idea is to take the size of a packet of compressed video and compare it against the next video packet size. If the size is larger then a binary 1 if not 0. I want to store this string of binary in multiple UINT32 variables in sequence (approx 2 seconds of 30 fps video) and compare them to each other in other videos with hamming distance.

I think that even though the data is compressed with different codecs, the "pattern" of changing pixels in the compressed data should still be similar.

Really I just want to know if anyone has tried this and knows it doesn't work or good reason why it won't work, of course if it is a good idea I'll take that too :)

Comment: Won't work. Different encoders will place key frames in different locations.

Comment: Not only are different codecs putting key frames in different places, they may also have different compression algorithms or different compression settings, so similar the same sequence may lose or not lose a particular (set of) pixel(s) movement. And of course, you'll get loads of false positives too, for videos that are not equal, because the size of packets are the same, but content completely different.

Comment: You will not find a solution that works with all codecs. Consider decoding just a tiny portion of the frame (if possible) and analyzing that.

Comment: I was hoping the difference with keyframes would be minimal, but good thing I asked. Talk about wasted effort